# Query to get maximum value based on timestamp every 4 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table that stores data every 15 minutes, but I want to fetch the maximum value every 4 hour.

This is my Actual table:

```
+----+----+----+-------------------------+
| Id | F1 | F2 |        timestamp        |
+----+----+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 24 | 30 | 2019-03-25 12:15:00.000 |
|  2 | 22 |  3 | 2019-03-25 12:30:00.000 |
|  3 |  2 |  4 | 2019-03-25 12:45:00.000 |
|  4 |  5 | 35 | 2019-03-25 13:00:00.000 |
|  5 | 18 | 23 | 2019-03-25 13:15:00.000 |
|  ' | '  |  ' | '                       |
| 16 | 21 | 34 | 2019-03-25 16:00:00.000 |
+----+----+----+-------------------------+
```

The Output I am looking for is:

```
+----+----+----+
| Id | F1 | F2 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 | 24 | 35 |1st 4 Hours
+----+----+----+
|  2 | 35 | 25 |Next 4 Hours
+----+----+----+
```

I did use the query

```
select max(F1) as F1,
       max(F2) as F2
from table
where timestamp>='2019/3/26 12:00:01'
  and timestamp<='2019/3/26 16:00:01'
```

and it returns the first 4 hours value but when I Increase the timestamp from 4 hrs to 8 hrs it will still give me 1 max value rather than 2 per 4 hours.

I did try with the group by clause but wasn't able to get the expected result.

Comment: is this per 4 hours, on the hour, in a 24 hour period e.g. 0, 4, 8 ,12,16,20:00 or every four hours from any given start point? e.g. 1:24,5:24,9:24,13:24...

Comment: ...and does the date range end (e.g. do you specify start/end dates, only want 24 hours, etc). Saying "this is my table" is great when you show us 6 rows. But surely your table will get bigger over time.

Comment: @TJB I am logging data every 15 minutes so the data will be in a very specific format: 2:00, 2:15,2:30,3:00, 3:15. And my start day would be first day of month and end day would be the last day of month. The data wont have any other timestamps like 1:24 and so on.

Comment: @AaronBertrand My start and end dates will be first and last day of the month. I know the table will grow and I have taken that into consideration in my architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT   Max(f1), 
         Max(f2), datepart(hh,timestamp), convert(date,timestamp) 
FROM     TABLE 
WHERE    datepart(hh,timestamp)%4 = 0 
AND timestamp>='2019/3/26 12:00:01' 
AND      timestamp<='2019/3/26 16:00:01'
GROUP BY datepart(hh,timestamp), convert(date,timestamp)
ORDER BY convert(date,timestamp) asc
```

Comment: Another `WHERE` after the `ORDER BY`? That isn't valid syntax. The `WHERE` goes after the `FROM` and `ON` clauses and before the `GROUP BY`, no where else, and there can't be two.

Comment: @MatthewEvans This works if my date range is 1 day but if I increase the date range to a month which I am looking for then it just gives me only 6 values.

Comment: @MatthewEvans This is very close but I am getting the results sorted by hours and not by date. So I wanted 2019-3-26 0,2019-3-26 4,2019-3-26 8....... but what I am getting is  2019-3-26 0,2019-3-27 0,2019-3-28 0......... Hope that makes sense.

Comment: its ordered by date, then 4 hour periods

Comment: @MatthewEvans I removed the datepart(hh,timestamp) from the order by clause and got what I was looking for. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple method:

```
select convert(date, timestamp) as dte,
       (datepart(hour, timestamp) / 4) * 4 as hour,
       max(F1) as F1,
       max(F2) as F2
from table
group by convert(date, timestamp), (datepart(hour, timestamp) / 4) * 4;
```

This puts the date and hour into separate columns; you can use `dateadd()` to put them in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
declare @startingDatetime datetime = '2017-10-04 12:00:00';
select grp, max(F1) F1, max(F2) F2
from (
    select datediff(hour, @startingDatetime, [timestamp]) / 4 grp, *
    from MyTable
    where [timestamp] > @startingDatetime
) a group by grp
```

Comment: What is StartTime? Is it a timestamp column?